# Mix WxWidgets and GTK+

Tags: linux, user-interface, gtk, wxwidgets

I want to write a GUI in GTK+ on Linux in which I want to embed as a widget a GUI written in WxWidgets. The reason is that I want to use the GUI that's already developed by someone else in WxWidgets and add my own elements, but I am more familiar with GTK+ and would like not to have to learn a new toolkit.

I am familiar and have used GtkPlug/GtkSocket which use the Xembed protocol. I wonder is there a similar feature in WxWidgets that will allow me to achieve the same? I presume I will be using wxGTK on Linux so potentially there could be a way to hack into the underlying GTK and use GtkSocket/Plug. Any other way to achieve that would be appreciated as well.

I tried looking for that online but didn't find any recent article explaining that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to provide a `GtkPlug` for a `wxWindow` but AFAIK nobody has ever done this. There are patches implementing `GtkSocket` from wxWidgets side but I don't think this is going to help you much.

Comment: Hm, there is a `wxWindow::GetHandle` function which returns various system dependent things, among which is a GtkWidget under wxGTK. My guess is that if I try linking with both libraries and running them in the same process I should be able to extract the Widget from Wx and manipulate it in GTK. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can get `GtkWidget*` from a `wxWindow`. But you shouldn't manipulate it directly, this risks breaking that window behaviour.

Comment: Right, I will just steal its Xwindows ID.